How do I write a powershell function to send a warning if files don't exist?
I am new to powershell scripting and I am trying to create a function that sends a warning to my email if a list of files do not exist in my C: drive folder. The list of files I am looking for are:
file1pop_*.txt
transaction_*.txt
card_*.txt
account_*.txt
I know to create a function I write it like function File-Warnings
Do I use WarningAction for this specific scenario?

Welcome to SO, Forgottenluv. Please review the information under [help], especially [ask]. [Edit] the question to include an MRE ([mre]), describe what does happen, and describe what should happen.

You might want to start with a StackOverflow query like powershell send email.

This is the function that you need:
function Send-FileWarnings {
    param (
        [string]$FolderPath,
        [string]$SmtpServer,
        [string]$From,
        [string]$To,
        [string]$Subject
    )
    $filesList = @("file1pop_*.txt", "transaction_*.txt", "card_*.txt", "account_*.txt")
    $missingFiles = @()
    foreach ($pattern in $filesList) {
        $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Filter $pattern -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($files.Count -eq 0) {
            $missingFiles += "No files found matching pattern: $pattern"
        }
    }
    if ($missingFiles.Count -gt 0) {
        $body = "WARNING: The following file patterns are missing in folder $FolderPath :`n`n" + ($missingFiles -join "`n")
        Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Body $body
    }
}


Example of usage:
Send-FileWarnings -FolderPath "C:\Folder" -SmtpServer "smtpserver" -From "alert@test.com" -To "you@test.com" -Subject "File Alert"


Information of cmdlets ussed:

Send-MailMessage

Get-ChildItem


Regards!

thanks this was really helpful. how do i throw an error in the code after "$missingFiles += "No files found matching pattern: $pattern"" like if i don't want to send an email, just throw an error in the code itself if those list of files don't appear in the source location

I'm glad you found it useful, if it's the answer you were looking for, you could do it with the following code:
$errorMessage = "ERROR: The following file patterns are missing in folder $FolderPath:`n`n" + ($missingFiles -join "`n")

Throw $errorMessage
}
}```
